# ¿Por qué no funciona esta petición AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Llevo alrededor de una semana para pasar una variable de javascript a php, y ya me estoy volviendo loco. Tras informarme mucho, empecé por hacer una petición en ajax.

Cuando lo ejecuto, donde me debería imprimir la variable $IDbutton, me da el siguiente error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "IDbutton" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro\Pagina.php on line 2267.

Sin embargo en la consola no da ningún error, solo muestra "hecho", lo que se imprime cuando la función ajax tiene éxito. Con lo poco que sé de programación, creo que el problema está en que no se envía la variable. Cualquier aportación me ayudaría. Muchas gracias por adelantado.
Este es el código de la petición ajax:

```
<script>
var IDbutton = '12';
$.ajax({
 method: 'post',
 url: 'Pagina.php',
 data: {IDbutton1: IDbutton},
 success: function() {
  console.log('hecho');
 }
});
</script>
```

Y aquí es donde obtengo la variable en php:

```
<?php
 $IDbutton1 = $_POST['IDbutton1'];
 print_r($_POST['IDbutton1']);
 var_dump($IDbutton1);
 echo $IDbutton1;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

En data tienes `{IDbutton: IDbutton}`. Yo creería que no estás enviando lo que supones.

Lo que yo haría para hacer debug es, en el PHP que recibe la petición, hacer un `var_dump` o un `print_r($_POST)` para saber lo que se está pintando. Siempre, no sólo en esta ocasión.

Yo apuesto varios frijolitos a que la variable que viaja en el cuerpo de tu petición no tiene el ID que esperas porque estás usando **la variable** `IDbutton`, no la etiqueta `'IDbutton'`. ¿Será posible que esté viajando un `{12 : 12}`? De hecho, el warning te está diciendo exactamente eso, pero no veo que hagas debug de lo que recibe tu script PHP para trabajar.

Comment: @Alfaravo Ya he cambiado el nombre de la variable de php a idbutton1 por si acaso, pero sigue ocurriendo. Haciendo el var_dump me da "NULL". Soy bastante nuevo y no entiendo cual es la solución.

Comment: y el `print_r` sobre la variable POST?

Comment: Me repite el mismo error que cuando imprimo la variable IDbutton1

Comment: Por favor, pon en tu pregunta el código completo, incluyendo el código que estás usando en el PHP para hacer debug. Está difícil adivinar qué estás haciendo. PD. eso de ponerle la variable php `idbutton1` no arregla nada tampoco.

Comment: ya lo he añadido.

Answer (score 1):

1. En `data:` debes usar comillas simples o comillas dobles para enviar el `name` *o nombre del campo* y posteriormente la variable con el `value` *o valor del campo*. Algo así: `data: {'IDbutton': IDbutton},`.
2. Luego, en `success: function()` puedes recibir la respuesta de `php` para mostrarla en la consola, en un `alert` o incluso en alguna parte de tu `html`.

```
<script>
var IDbutton = '12';
$.ajax({
 method: 'post',
 url: 'Pagina.php',
 data: {'IDbutton': IDbutton},
 success: function(respuesta) {
  //Respuesta de php en la consola
  console.log(respuesta);
 }
});
</script>
```

3. Con lo anterior, deberías recibir en **Pagina.php** los datos como si lo estuvieses enviando directamente desde un formulario. Puedes usar `print_r($_POST);` para ver un `array` con toda la información que estás recibiendo a través del método `$_POST`, o simplemente un `echo ($_POST['IDbutton'];` para ver específicamente lo que estás recibiendo en ese campo.

```
<?php
 //Puedes usar esto, que te mostraría un array con toda la estructura 
 print_r($_POST);
 //O esto, que te debería mostrar en la consola en número 12
 echo ($_POST['IDbutton'];
?>
```

Al final, comenta o elimina el `print_r($_POST);`.

Comment: Lo he hecho pero nada, sigue igual. ¡¡¡¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?!!!

Comment: No es necesario usar comillas para nombrar los campos de `data`, ahí se crea un objeto Javascript simplemente, de hecho, si observas los [ejemplos de la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), se crean los nombres de cada propiedad sin comillas. Y, para depurar el código es mejor usar `var_dump`, pues los nulos y los false no serán mostrados con `print_r`